# Loading Zeppelin Helium package from local repository is not working

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have created one helium package and the all the files are locally available. Following is my package.json, it worked absolutely fine on Zeppelin-0.8.snapshot version but on Zeppelin-0.7.2, I am getting an error that the package is not found in npm registry. Why it is searching for this in the npm registry? I have also tried providing absolute path but same error.

```
{
  "type" : "VISUALIZATION",
  "name" : "zeppelin_helium_XXX",
  "description" : "XXXX",
  "artifact" : "./zeppelin-helium-verity",
  "license" : "Apache-2.0",
  "icon" : "<img>Removed the actual base64 string</img>"
}
```

Comment: Hi, Helium spec doesn't support the relative path in `artifact` field. Could you change it to the absolute path?

Comment: Additionally, 0.7.X doens't support `AdvancedTransformation` for helium visualization. What kind of transformation did you use for your viz package?

Comment: Hi I tried with absolute path as well, still it was looking into npm registry. So far I am not using AdvanceTransformation but I need to use this feature as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening?